# Storing constant webdriver elements in an enum

Tags: java, selenium, enums, webdriver

I currently store my element locations in a separate class away from their accessor methods and I am looking for a more efficient way of storing them. From what I have read an Enum if the way to go. My questions are is my assumption correct? and how do I implement it? The following is a small example of how it works now:

Elements class:

```
public class GeneralJobElements {
    protected By ProcurementWorkFlow = By.name("procurementWorkflow");
    protected By JobOwner = By.name("jobOwner");
    protected By JobTitle = By.name("i18n_jobTitle_minimized");
```

}

Accessor class:

```
public class CreateJobGeneralTabActions extends GeneralJobElements {
    public CreateJobGeneralTabActions selectJobOwner(int index) {

    logMessage(JobOwner, "Job Owner");
    Select sele = new Select(getWebElement(JobOwner));
    sele.selectByIndex(index);

    return this;
}
```

public CreateJobGeneralTabActions fillJobTitle() {

```
    logMessage(JobTitle, "Job Title");
    getWebElement(JobTitle).sendKeys(JOB_TITLE);
    logger.info("The job title is:  " + JOB_TITLE);

    return this;
}

public CreateJobGeneralTabActions selectJobApprovalWF(int index) {

    logMessage(ProcurementWorkFlow, "Procurement Workflow");
    Select sele = new Select(getWebElement(ProcurementWorkFlow));
    sele.selectByIndex(index);

    return this;
}
```

I dont like they idea that I am extending the elements class

Comment: Where did you read that using an Enum would be useful?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think storing locators in Enum is a good idea, neither is storing locators in properties files. Both have issues. Instead I would recommend you to use [PageFactory](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) which supports [PageObjects](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects).

1. For debugging, updating, adding elements, you need to jump to external properties files or enums. In `PageFactory`, elements would be annotated with `@FindBy` annotations and they are right there in the Page Object so that you can easily work with them
2. `PageFactory` would find elements for you, thus avoiding the overhead of driver.findElement or driver.findElements boilerplate code
3. When `PageFactory` fails finding an element, it would throw an exception, POINTING exactly where it failed.
4. PageFactory can support for element load, caching etc. No coding required from your side
5. Maintaining properties files is pain, they grow quickly, you may add duplicate keys etc. Also the overhead of parsing and reading the keys. All this could be avoided if you use `PageFactory`

Browser automation is a hard problem to solve, not to mention the ever evolving app under test and need to support different browsers/platforms. Therefore we should avoid adding more layers which adds complexities and instead make use of solutions provided by open source teams as much as possible.